# Fatal error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: phantomjs, qunit, spawn, enoent, grunt-contrib-qunit

Gruntfile.js content:

```
grunt.initConfig({
        connect: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    port: 5005,
                    base: '.'
                }
            }
        },
        qunit: {
            all: ['test/*.html']
        }
    });

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');

grunt.registerTask('test', ['connect', 'qunit']);
```

Test/index.html file content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>
            Sitejson - QUnit Test Runner
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/qunit/qunit.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="qunit"></div>
        <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>

        <script src="libs/qunit/qunit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="testcases/tests.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

tests.js content:

```
QUnit.test("hello test", function(assert) {
    assert.ok(1 == "1", "Passed!");
});
```

I am working on Ubuntu / Linux environment. I have also installed Phantomjs and is working fine. Whenever i try to run grunt test I'm receiving a fatal error: spawn ENOENT error.

whereas i try running it on browser its qunit is working fine...

I am not able to identify what the issues. Am i missing some more configuration over here.

grunt test --debug shows me:

```
Running "connect:server" (connect) task
[D] Task source: /media/hegdeashwin/Storage-TB/qunittesting/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/tasks/connect.js
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:5005

Running "qunit:all" (qunit) task
[D] Task source: /media/hegdeashwin/Storage-TB/qunittesting/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/tasks/qunit.js
Testing test/index.html [D] ["/media/hegdeashwin/Storage-TB/qunittesting/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/phantomjs/main.js","/tmp/1405775714604.2773","test/index.html","{\"timeout\":5000,\"inject\":\"/media/hegdeashwin/Storage-TB/qunittesting/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/phantomjs/bridge.js\",\"urls\":[],\"force\":false,\"console\":true,\"httpBase\":false}"]
Fatal error: spawn EACCES
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

- set the `tmpdir` environment variable:

  ```
  setenv TMPDIR=~/tmp
  ```
- Rerun the `grunt` task
- If it works, set this permanently by adding the following to your `.bashrc` or `.profile`:

  ```
  export TMPDIR=~/tmp
  ```

**References**

- [Troubleshooting · npm/npm Wiki](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)
- [Secure Programs HowTo](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Secure-Programs-HOWTO/)
- [Environment Variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xbd/envvar.html)
- [FAQ Troubleshooting](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting)